# Varargs in LLVM

Tags: llvm

Can I define a vararg function in LLVM, if yes how can I access its arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Use the standard `#include <stdarg.h>`, create a va_list, and have at it.  Define your function as using the C-calling convention.

cf:   http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#callingconv